# Improving Linq to entities query with not mapped properties

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq-to-entities, iqueryable

I'm having lot of problems to get the a query properly built before sending it to the server to retrieve filtered results, fisrt i was querying against a hole result set of orders then appliying a order items filter with a calculated property, when trying to refactor to get only the set of orders matching the items criteria, of course i'm getting the error: The specified type member 'ReceivableQuantity' is not supported in LINQ to Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties are supported. 
Below the working code:

```
pendingOrders = from o in this.GetAll()
                where o.OrderItems.Where(i => i.ReceivableQuantity > 0).Count() > 0
                select new Order()
                {
                       OrderNumber = o.OrderNumber,
                       Comments = o.Comments,
                       FinalApprover = o.FinalApprover,
                       OrderDate = o.OrderDate,
                       Requisitioner = o.Requisitioner,
                       SupplierName = o.SupplierName,
                       ID = o.ID,
                       ShoppingCartName = o.ShoppingCartName,
                       OrderItems = (from i in o.OrderItems 
                                     where i.ReceivableQuantity > 0
                                     select i).OrderBy(i => i.LineNumber).ToList()
                };
```

This is the NotMapped Property in the OrderItem Class:

```
    [NotMapped]
    public decimal ReceivableQuantity
    {
        get
        {
            if (Order == null)
                return 0;

            decimal response;
            response = this.MatchedQuantity - this.ReceivedQuantity;

            if (response >= 0)
                return response;
            else
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("Receivable Quantity must be greater than 0.");
        }
    }
```

MatchedQuantity and ReceivedQuantity are also NotMapped properties, so i think this is really extending.

What's the best approach i shoud use, now that the site using it is already running, and with the database growing everyday the features using the code are becoming realy slow.

Thanks in advance for your help.
Lio.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are using code first mapping. This approach is quite limited when it comes to advanced querying because it still doesn't support SQL function mapping. Because of that you have these options:

- Put whole computation of all your not mapped properties directly into Linq-to-entities query. That can make your query quite nasty.
- Get rid of that query and use two stored procedures - 1st to get all orders matching your criteria and second to get all order items of all orders matching your criteria. You can call those stored procedures with `Database.SqlQuery`.
- Don't use EF and execute the query with SQL directly. In such case you can even use one SQL command with two queries ore one stored procedure with two queries.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Ladislav, i'm using SQLCE, so the stored procedures is not the solution, in other hand, i'm far away of being good at writing T-SQL :), that's why i picked EF as the data access technology because is really easier to wite linq than T-SQL, will continue trying to find a solution before start attempting to write the SQL query